# How to set default value to a certain column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to set the default value to a particular column but i don't need for all rows. I need to set only for those whose location is 'India'

Please can anyone help me in setting up where clause.

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD CONSTRAINT df_City
DEFAULT 'Mumbai' FOR City;
```

Answer (score -1):

That isn't how a `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT` works, they are for when the column is *omitted* from the `INSERT`; they can't have conditional logic such as 'When ColA equals "B" then "C" otherwise "D"'.

Instead this is logic that should be defined in your `INSERT` statement. For example:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.Persons (Name, Country, City)
VALUES(@Name, @Country, ISNULL(@City,CASE @Country WHEN 'India' THEN 'Mumbai' END);
```

That isn't scalable though, so if you have many different conditional defaults (for `City`) I'd suggest you use a "lookup table", and `JOIn` to that:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.Persons (Name, Country, City)
SELECT V.Name,
       V.Country
       ISNULL(@City,DC.City) --If both the parameter and default are NULL will result in NULL still
FROM (VALUES(@Name, @Country, @City))V(Name,Country,City)
     LEFT JOIN dbo.DefaultCity ON V.Country = DC.Country;
```